# Gin send metrics to promethesus where the URL has a parameter in the path

Tags: go, prometheus, go-gin

I have a gin service where one of the endpoint looks like this:

```
const myPath= "/upload-some-file/:uuid"
```

In my middleware that sends data to prometheus, I have something like this:

```
requestCounter = promauto.NewCounterVec(prometheus.CounterOpts{
    Name: "all-http-requests",
    Help: "Total number of http requests",
}, []string{"Method", "Endpoint"})

func Telemetry() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        // Metrics for requests volume
        requestCounter.With(prometheus.Labels{"Method": c.Request.Method, "Endpoint": c.Request.URL.Path}).Inc()

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

But I notice that that prometheus is unable to figure out that a parameter is actually embedded into the path, therefore it treats every unique uuid as a new path.

Is there some way to let prometheus realize that it is actually using a URL with embedded parameters?

Comment: Why not just check '/upload-some-file/' part of URL

Comment: Your mental model seems to be off. a) you don't "send" data to prometheus but prometheus scrapes the metrics using the /metric endpoint of your server. b) prometheus doesn't care what your label values are, not one bit, so no you cannot make prometheus "realize" anything (there are the rewriting rules, but that's the wrong hammer for this nail). You just have to set the label value correctly in the first place. I don't know how to do it in gin. Have you checked if the route pattern is available in the context?

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/748#issuecomment-543683781

So I can simply do `c.FullPath()` to get the matched route.